# How to move turtles on a game board simulation?

Tags: netlogo

I'm creating a board game simulation similar to monopoly, where pieces are moving around the board. My turtle acts as the user's game piece and moves around the border of the world. The border is set up in alternating colors. I have a button that generates the number of steps the turtle moves. Those steps are stored as dice-num, a global variable. However, when the turtle lands on the patches before the patch (16 -16) (the bottom right-hand corner of the board) and the number of steps it needs to move exceeds 1, I can't turn the turtle's heading halfway to move up the board. As a result it only moves back to the beginning of the board.

I've tried to treat each case separately:

```
     ;if the turtle lands on the patch before the corner
     ask turtle 0 [if pycor = min-pycor and pxcor = max-pxcor - 1 
       [setxy max-pxcor min-pycor
         set dice-num dice-num - 1 
       show dice-num
         ]
       ]
```

;dice-num refers to number of steps the turtle moves

Heres my code so far:

```
    to setup
     board
    end

  to go
   dice-roll
  end 

  to board
  ask patches [if pxcor = max-pxcor or pycor = max-pycor or pxcor = min- 
  pxcor or pycor = min-pycor
  [set pcolor blue]]

ask patches [if pycor = max-pycor or pycor = min-pycor
 [if pxcor mod 2 = 0
   [set pcolor orange]]]

ask patches [if pxcor = max-pxcor or pxcor = min-pxcor
 [if pycor mod 2 = 0
   [set pcolor orange]]]

 ask patch min-pxcor min-pycor [set pcolor green]
end

to dice-roll
  set dice [1 2 3 4 5 6]
  set dice-num one-of dice
  user-message (word "You rolled: " dice-num)
  ask turtle 0 [
  fd dice-num
  ]

 ;allows the turtle to turn if it lands on a corner
 ask turtle 0 [if ycor = min-pycor and xcor = max-pxcor [set heading 0]
  if xcor = max-pxcor and ycor = max-pycor [set heading 270] 
  if xcor = min-pxcor and ycor = max-pycor [set heading 180]
 ;add a statement to end game once player rereaches the green patch
 ]

 ;if the turtle lands on the patch before the corner
 ask turtle 0 [if pycor = min-pycor and pxcor = max-pxcor - 1 
   [setxy max-pxcor min-pycor
 set dice-num dice-num - 1 
 show dice-num
   ]
 ]
 end
```

I expect the output to be the turtle to start moving up the right hand side of the board once it lands on the patch (15 -16) and recieves a dice-num greater than 1. However, when the turtle does land on the patch (15 -16) and the dice-num is greater than 1 it simply moves back to the beginning of the board.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this was simply too long for comments so I had to make some guesses. I expect the problem was that you were forwarding the full amount of the die roll after checking location. This would mean you have to test all the potential patches that could reach the corner. Instead, it is easier to move one patch and test location before moving the next patch. This is a cleaned up version of your code that implements this move and check process.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  board
  ask one-of patches with [pcolor = green]
  [ sprout 1
    [ set color white
      set heading 90
      forward 1
    ]
  ]
end

to go
  let die-num dice-roll
  ask one-of turtles [ move die-num ]
end 

to board
  ask patches with [ pxcor = max-pxcor or pxcor = min-pxcor ]
  [ set pcolor ifelse-value (pycor mod 2 = 0) [orange][blue] ]
  ask patches with [ pycor = max-pycor or pycor = min-pycor ]
  [ set pcolor ifelse-value (pxcor mod 2 = 0) [orange][blue] ]
  ask patch min-pxcor min-pycor [set pcolor green]
end

to-report dice-roll
  let dice-num one-of [1 2 3 4 5 6]
  user-message (word "You rolled: " dice-num)
  report dice-num
end

to move [#roll]
  while [ #roll > 0 ]
  [ if pxcor = max-pxcor and pycor = max-pycor [set heading one-of [180 270] ]
    if pxcor = max-pxcor and pycor = min-pycor [set heading one-of [0 270] ]
    if pxcor = min-pxcor and pycor = max-pycor [set heading one-of [180 90] ]
    if pxcor = min-pxcor and pycor = min-pycor [ stop ]
    fd 1
    set #roll #roll - 1
  ]
end
```

The alternative is simply to add the die roll to the current location and see if it goes past. If it does, calculate where you want to get to.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick reply, but I don't quite understand to move [#roll] procedure. What does the #roll stand for? Lastly, why is it necessary to set the headings one of 2 different degrees? Thank you in advance!

Comment: A procedure with [ ] after the name accepts an input or argument. In this case, the number from the die is passed to the procedure so it knows how many patches to move. That allows the die rolling to be separated from the moving (though it is perfectly fine to keep them together like your move procedure). The choice of heading is because I didn't know what your rules were supposed to be - does it reverse, turn or what? So I basically had it randomly choose a legal direction. That doesn't matter for your question - the problem was about moving forward at once or one patch at a time.